# Printing bits of a byte

Tags: assembly, x86

I am using "lahf" to store the flags in ah. I would like to output these values (1s and 0s) to see my flags, but I have no idea how. My Holder label in the code below outputs a decimal, is there a way to output a binary number instead? or should I go about this in a different way?

```
lahf                 ;moves flags to ah
mov [flagg], ah      ;moves flags to label "flagg" in .bss (reserved 1 dword)


;later on...
mov eax,[flagg]      ;moves the flag values into eax
push eax             ;pushes eax onto stack
push Holder          ;Holder is a label in .data ( "%d",0 )
call printf          ;prints to screen
add esp, 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't print binary with `printf`. You *could* print hex which is quite easy to relate to its binary representation (with `%02X` e.g.).

If you insist on printing binary, you would have to write a function for it. The function would be quite simple. If you have `n` bits, you could loop `n` times, do a [shift](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Shift_and_Rotate) by 1 and based on the carry either print 0 or 1. A bit more efficiently, you could store the result in a buffer and then print it all at once with `%s`.

Depending on how much memory you have (since it's x86 it's unlikely (impossible?) that it's embedded, so you probably do have a lot of memory), you can also store a table with the '0'-'1' representations of the bytes. That table would take 256*(8+1) bytes (one for '\0' if you use `%s`) for 8-bit values and you would need to hard-code it (perhaps generate with another program).

So far, I told you the two extremes: calculate all vs store all. The first can be slow and the second take a lot of space (and also tedious to generate).

To get the best of both worlds, you can have a table that stores the '0'-'1' representations of nibbles (4 bits). That table would be a mere 16*(8+1) bytes. Printing a byte would then be printing first its most significant and then its least significant nibble.

In C, this would look like this:

```
const char *bit_rep[16][5] = {
    [ 0] = "0000", [ 1] = "0001", [ 2] = "0010", [ 3] = "0011",
    [ 4] = "0100", [ 5] = "0101", [ 6] = "0110", [ 7] = "0111",
    [ 8] = "1000", [ 9] = "1001", [10] = "1010", [11] = "1011",
    [12] = "1100", [13] = "1101", [14] = "1110", [15] = "1111",
};

void print_byte(uint8_t byte)
{
    printf("%s%s", bit_rep[byte >> 4], bit_rep[byte & 0x0F]);
}
```